# Text field swapper like clear trip

Tags: jquery, css

I need a text field swapper where i can swap from and destination just like cleartrip website using jquery and CSS3? It is something like if i click on a button or arrow it will swap the text field and change the source and destination field values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a jquery and CSS3 transition property to get a cleartrip like effect in out textbox. Check out this excellent article on it on this [link](http://intelliwins.com/blog/post/Textbox-Swapper-with-Jquery-and-CSS3)

Here we have used CSS 3 transition property to create a animation like effect to change the textbox.

You can also download the source code for it.